# What's a good way to detect ambient EMF from a distance?

Tags: antenna

I am an artist working on a project that, distilled for simplicity, will change the color of LED lighting based on ambient EMF. I've got a prototype built (based on [A MAKE magazine project video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1Bke3750WE)) which uses seven different colored LEDs instead of a seven segment LED.

Here's my challenge: I will be placing the device in the center of a gallery space (roughly 10x10), and so far, all of my testing with the 6-ish inch whip antenna on the board require me to move the device within inches of devices to get a signal.

So...what next? I know there's EMF from the electrical in the walls. I know that patrons of the gallery will likely have mobile devices that will increase the ambient EMF. But...how do I detect these subtle changes from a sensor mounted on the ceiling? Would a larger antenna help? If so, what are some design considerations for such an antenna? The bigger the better? or is it more a shape issue (e.g., round ball of copper wire vs. a copper wire just kinda hanging there)? Or is it something that ANY antenna will pick up, but I need to use an Op Amp or additional circuitry to amplify the antenna input to detect the subtle changes?

I'm not 100% percent sure this is an antenna issue or a signal amplification issue, so I'm not sure if I'm asking appropriate questions. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your circuit at the moment and what research have you done that might give an idea if what electric fields prevail in your environment?

Comment: roughly 10x10 metres? feet? furlong?

Comment: possibly helpful: ["RIDICULOUSLY SENSITIVE
ELECTRIC CHARGE DETECTOR"](http://amasci.com/emotor/chargdet.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want : http://www.linear.com/product/LT5534, it's an IC chip to detect RF frequencies, including cell phone frequencies.

Be aware that a cell phone is not permanently generating an EMF, only bursts if not during a call (although smartphones may exhibit more activity with background apps, the OS, etc...).

Comment: Very much this. I've looked at cell-phones with a spectrum analyser. Unless you're doing something active (streaming music, etc...), they don't produce much EMF. There is a huge incentive to keep the radio on as little as possible - battery life.